# How to trigger a jQuery function every time new option is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML `<form>` with `<select>`able dropdown `<option>`s where each `<option>` has a value tag that represents price of the selected vehicle.

I would like this `<div class="price-here">` to display the value of the selected option everytime `<option class="b">` is selected.

In my code I used `change()` function but it doesn't seem to work. What is wrong?

**HTML + CSS:**

```
<script>
    $('select.car-selector').change(function () {
      var packagePrice = $(".car-selector option.b:selected").val();
      $('div.price-here').text(packagePrice + " USD");
    });
</script>
<form>
  <select class="car-selector">
    <option class="a" value="" selected>Select brand</option>
    <option class="b" value="150">Volvo</option>
    <option class="b" value="350">Saab</option>
    <option class="b" value="150">Opel</option>
    <option class="b" value="500">Audi</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br /><br />
<div class="price-here">Default price</div>
```

Comment: You need to wrap code in document-ready handler or move code to bottom of page

Comment: ^ or place the `<script>` tag just before the `</body>`. Closing as a typo either way

Comment: there is no `select.car-selector` at the time you try to add the `change` event listener. The node is created after the script has been executed.

Comment: Just move your script tag after form tag.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$('select.car-selector').change(function () {   
    if($(this).hasClass('b')){
        var packagePrice = $(".car-selector").val();
        $('div.price-here').html(packagePrice + " USD");
    }
    else
       $('div.price-here').html('');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By simply using **HTML** you can add a `disabled` attribute to the first option `<option class="a" value="" selected disabled>Select brand</option>`.

And once the end user selects some option will be no possible to go back to the option "Select brand".

```js
$('select.car-selector').change(function () {       
  var packagePrice = $('.car-selector option.b:selected').val();
  $('div.price-here').text(packagePrice + ' USD');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select class="car-selector">
    <option class="a" value="" selected disabled>Select brand</option>
    <option class="b" value="150">Volvo</option>
    <option class="b" value="350">Saab</option>
    <option class="b" value="150">Opel</option>
    <option class="b" value="500">Audi</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br /><br />
<div class="price-here">Default price</div>
```

Or with **JavaScript** you most to check `packagePrice` is not `undefined` and you can do it with a [Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) `packagePrice ? packagePrice + ' USD' : 'Default price'`.

```js
$('select.car-selector').change(function () {       
  var packagePrice = $('.car-selector option.b:selected').val(),
      text = packagePrice ? packagePrice + ' USD' : 'Default price';
  $('div.price-here').text(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select class="car-selector">
    <option class="a" value="" selected>Select brand</option>
    <option class="b" value="150">Volvo</option>
    <option class="b" value="350">Saab</option>
    <option class="b" value="150">Opel</option>
    <option class="b" value="500">Audi</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br /><br />
<div class="price-here">Default price</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Check `value` instead of class `b`, so remove class `b` of selector and check `value` like this , if value be `""` show `Defalut price` else show `value`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select.car-selector').change(function () {       
      var packagePrice = $(".car-selector option:selected").val();
      packagePrice = $.trim(packagePrice);
      if(packagePrice !=="")
        $('div.price-here').text(packagePrice + " USD");
      else 
        $('div.price-here').text('Default price');
    })
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select.car-selector').change(function () {       
      var packagePrice = $(".car-selector option:selected").val();
      packagePrice = $.trim(packagePrice);
      if(packagePrice !=="")
        $('div.price-here').text(packagePrice + " USD");
      else 
        $('div.price-here').text('Default price');
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<form>
  <select class="car-selector">
    <option class="a" value="" selected>Select brand</option>
    <option class="b" value="150">Volvo</option>
    <option class="b" value="350">Saab</option>
    <option class="b" value="250">Opel</option>
    <option class="b" value="500">Audi</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br /><br />
<div class="price-here">Default price</div>
```

> **In your case :** `packagePrice` is value option with class `b` that user selected it, so when user selects first option with class `a` `packagePrice` get value `undefined`.

**For fix it:** you must check `packagePrice` is `undefined` or not.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select.car-selector').change(function () {       
      var packagePrice = $(".car-selector option.b:selected").val();
      if(packagePrice!=undefined)
        $('div.price-here').text(packagePrice + " USD");
      else
        $('div.price-here').text("Default price");
    });
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select.car-selector').change(function () {       
      var packagePrice = $(".car-selector option.b:selected").val();
      if(packagePrice!=undefined)
        $('div.price-here').text(packagePrice + " USD");
      else
        $('div.price-here').text("Default price");
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<form>
  <select class="car-selector">
    <option class="a" value="" selected>Select brand</option>
    <option class="b" value="150">Volvo</option>
    <option class="b" value="350">Saab</option>
    <option class="b" value="150">Opel</option>
    <option class="b" value="500">Audi</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br /><br />
<div class="price-here">Default price</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45818443/how-to-trigger-a-jquery-function-every-time-new-option-is-selected#comment78594346_45818443)

> there is no `select.car-selector` at the time you try to add the change event listener.

You can check for the existence of a DOM element by returning its length: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-test-whether-an-element-exists/

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  console.log("Before: ", $("select.car-selector").length);
  // $("select.car-selector") is not in the DOM
  $('select.car-selector').change(function() {
    var packagePrice = $(".car-selector option.b:selected").val();
    $('div.price-here').text(packagePrice + " USD");
  });
</script>
<form>
  <select class="car-selector">
    <option class="a" value="" selected>Select brand</option>
    <option class="b" value="150">Volvo</option>
    <option class="b" value="350">Saab</option>
    <option class="b" value="150">Opel</option>
    <option class="b" value="500">Audi</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br /><br />
<div class="price-here">Default price</div>

<script>
  console.log("After: ", $("select.car-selector").length);
  // select.car-selector exists in the DOM
</script>
```

So, the solution is to include the `.change` script *after* the element it refers to.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  console.log("Before: ", $("select.car-selector").length);
</script>
<form>
  <select class="car-selector">
    <option class="a" value="" selected>Select brand</option>
    <option class="b" value="150">Volvo</option>
    <option class="b" value="350">Saab</option>
    <option class="b" value="150">Opel</option>
    <option class="b" value="500">Audi</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br /><br />
<div class="price-here">Default price</div>

<script>
  console.log("After: ", $("select.car-selector").length);
  $('select.car-selector').change(function() {
    var packagePrice = $(".car-selector option.b:selected").val();
    $('div.price-here').text(packagePrice + " USD");
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use ids and the value you need to get is the one from the select onot from the options.

```js
    $('#car-selector').change(function () {       
      var packagePrice = $("#car-selector").val();
      $('div.price-here').text(packagePrice + " USD");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select id="car-selector">
    <option class="a" value="" selected>Select brand</option>
    <option class="b" value="150">Volvo</option>
    <option class="b" value="350">Saab</option>
    <option class="b" value="150">Opel</option>
    <option class="b" value="500">Audi</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br /><br />
<div class="price-here">Default price</div>
```

Comment: Using an ID is unnecessary and doesn't change anything. The problem in his snippet is execution order, that his code is executed before the node is created.

Comment: Yeah there are not necessaries but in my experience you better should use ids in that kind of cases. That could prevent further mistakes.

Comment: I avoid IDs as much as possible as they don't scale very well *(since they have to be unique)*. But the main point is not the used selector but execution order. And changing the selector to an ID doesn't change anything about that.